# Does C++ guarantee that the address of a Base subobject will be the same as the address of its Derived object in case of single inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, memory-management

Here is a piece of code:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void Foo() override { }
    unsigned long long some_new_data_members[42];
};

int test_offset()
{
    Derived object{};
    Base* base_subobject = &object;

    return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(base_subobject) - reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&object);
}
```

The function `test_offset` always returns 0 on all versions of gcc, clang and msvc compilers that I have checked.

My question is: does the C++ standard guarantee that this function will be *always* returning 0 **in case of single inheritance** between `Base` and `Derived`?
If it does not, can somebody provide a real-life example (maybe with some exotic platform) where this code will return something different from 0?

*Please do not answer about multiple inheritance!*

---

*upd.:*

As pointed out by user *VTT*, code like this can lead to a non-zero offset:

```
struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void Foo() { }
};
```

It yields an offset equal to the size of a pointer on msvc.

But the fundamental difference of this example from my code snippet is that the `Derived` class here introduces some new virtual functions. Thus, a new vtable pointer has to appear somewhere in `Derived`, and it might be placed before the `Base` subobject, giving us a non-zero offset.

So, now I want to ask more specifically about my scenario.
What if the `Base` class has already had some virtual functions, and `Derived` just overrides them without adding any new ones (although it might add some new non-static member fields).
Are such non-zero offsets possible in this particular case?

Comment: I would guess this is not guaranteed, but just implementation coincidence, but I know only about 1% of the standard, so this is just *guess*.

Comment: _"...Each direct and indirect base class is present, as base class subobject, within the object representation of the derived class __at implementation-defined offset__...."_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

Comment: In general, the answer would be "no".   The order in which base classes are allocated within a derived class is unspecified.   This means, among other things, that if we have a class `A` that is a base of class `B`, then the "`A` part" and the "`B` part" may have different addresses in memory.

Answer (score 8):

Property of the pointers to different objects to have the same value is called *pointer-interconvertible*. The standard lists all possible cases when this is guaranteed:

> **6.7.2 Compound types [basic.compound]**
>   **4** Two objects `a` and `b` are pointer-interconvertible if:
>   (4.1) they are the same object, or
>   (4.2) one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object (12.3), or
>   (4.3) one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, the first base class subobject of that object (12.2), or
>   (4.4) there exists an object `c` such that `a` and `c` are pointer-interconvertible, and `c` and `b` are pointer-interconvertible.
>   
>   If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_cast` (8.5.1.10). [Note: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. —end note ]

Example:

```
struct Base{};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void Foo() { }
};
```

offset will be 8 (on typical 64-bit platform) for extra vtable pointer added by `Derived` infront of Base class subobject.

Comment: ...possibly. Depending on the compiler.

Comment: Good point, thank you! But what if Derived does not add any new virtual functions, just overrides those declared in Base? Is such scenario possible in this case?

Comment: @Taras I've added some reference listing situations when this behavior is guaranteed. rules about base classes are listed in `(4.3)`

Comment: Perhaps emphasise the impact of standard layoutness on this as that's where `virtual` disqualifies your example

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that a class with virtual functions is not a standard-layout type, so the standard cannot give a **guarantee** per se. But still, If both `Base` and `Derived` have the same virtual functions (`Derived` does not add any new ones) -- is such situation with a non-zero offset possible _in practice_? If it is, on which platforms/compilers? Updated the question.