# Conversion of Pointer to Pointer Types

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

When working with inheritance, implicit conversions allow "convenient" upcasting. For example:

```
class A{};
class B : public A{};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A* pa = &b; // Implicit conversion from B* to A*
    return 0; 
}
```

The same does not hold true for pointers to pointers. For example:

```
int main()
{
    B* pb = &b;
    B** ppb = &pb;
    
    A** ppa0 = ppb; // cannot initialize a variable of type 'A **' with an lvalue of type 'B **'
    A** ppa1 = &pb; // cannot initialize a variable of type 'A **' with an rvalue of type 'B **'
    A** ppa2 = static_cast<A**>(&pb); // static_cast from 'B **' to 'A **' is not allowed
    A** ppa3 = &static_cast<A*>(pb); // cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'A *'
    return 0; 
}
```

The last error made me think that this behavior is probably related to the strict aliasing rule. On the other hand, there is an [exemption](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.lval#10.7) for the case when a value is accessed through a base class type. So why should a `A**` pointer not be allowed to hold the address of a `B**` pointer?

Comment: Because `*ptr` is a pointer to `B`, and not `A`. Where would you place any code that will magically transform one pointer to the other pointer?

Comment: Upcasting may change the address that is being pointed to (think multiple inheritance). That would not work with pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: there inheritance is between `A` and `B` and has implications on `A*` and `B*`. The story ends here. There is no inheritance between `A*` and `B*` and no further implications for `A**` and `B**`

Comment: Consider that it would let you write `*ppa0 = new A;`  and then `pb` would no longer point to a `B`.

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged C++14 specifically? The rules have been clarified in C++17 and are now much clearer.

Comment: @user17732522 In my project I am required to work with C++14. Other than that there are no more specific reasons.

Comment: Today I found out, that there is an entry in the infamous C++ FAQ about this topic. For reference: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#derivedptrptr-to-baseptrptr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I didn't notice the C++14 tag, my answer assumes C++17 or later.)

That you can cast a `B*` to an `A*` and access the result as an `A` object is not because there is an exemption in the aliasing rule. There is no such exemption. (Note that the aliasing rule you refer to has been fixed in later C++ revisions.)

For general `B` derived from some `A`, if you actually did cast a `B*` to a `A*` with a `reinterpret_cast`, the pointer value would generally still refer to the original `B` object and then the aliasing rule would apply and the access through the result would cause undefined behavior. Except when there is an object of the target type which is *pointer-interconvertible* with the object that the original pointer value refers to (which can happen for standard layout base classes such as in your trivial example), `reinterpret_cast` will not change the pointer value at all. `reinterpret_cast` then only affects the *type* of the expression, but not its value. (Or even worse, it may produce an unspecified value if there is alignment mismatch.)

However, a `static_cast` or implicit conversion from `B*` to `A*` is allowed. But that only works because it actually changes the value of the pointer from a pointer to some `B` object to a pointer to some `A` object, namely the `A` subobject of the `B` object. This may or may not involve a change of the address represented by the pointer value as well, but regardless, the important part is that the resulting value of type `A*` actually points to an object of type `A`.

`A**` is a pointer to an object of type `A*` and `B**` is a pointer to an object of type `B*`. If you intent to cast the `B**` to an `A**` in a useful way, then you would want that dereferencing the result twice will give an lvalue referring to some `A` object. But that would require not only casting the double pointer's value, but also changing the value of the (simple) pointer object that the value points to. Such a behavior would be very unexpected. A cast doesn't usually change any object's value.

When you use `reinterpret_cast` or a C-style cast to cast `B**` to `A**`, then you actually don't change the original `B**` pointer value and as a consequence you will get a `A**` that actually points to a `B*` object and again, because there is no exemption for `A*`/`B*`, accessing through the resulting pointer will cause undefined behavior for violating the aliasing rule.

Comment: Although this answer might fit C++17 more, it did the job of course correcting my thoughts. I was stuck, because I took *pointer interconvertability* for granted. Being able to name the problem I was able to find some related questions for further reading (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57493570/11155375) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75352917/11155375)). Therefore, this is the best answer for me personally.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a good reason not to let a `B**` implicitly convert to an `A**`. Consider this example:

```cpp
int main() {
    B*  pointsToB;
    A** mwaHaHa = &pointsToB; // not allowed
    *mwaHaHa = new A; // oops!
}
```

Notice that the effect of this code is to have a pointer of type `B*`, which is only supposed to be allowed to point at an object of type `B`, to instead be pointing at an object of type `A`. Oops! That’s not allowed.

Comment: This is a great answer that shows there is no need to delve into the standards to see that such a feature would be a bad idea. This is the answer I would provide to my colleagues if the question ever comes up again.